# Do someone have a solution for this error?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, joomla3.9

I have a syntax error in my index.php in lines 35 and 49. How can I fix it? My website shows the following error message
" *ERROR
WHOOPS! WE'VE GOT A PROBLEM
syntax error, unexpected end of file
The page you were looking for doesn't exist. Sorry about that."*

**Here is the code:**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) Extensionsforjoomla.com - E4J - Templates for Joomla
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <https://e4j.com/>.
 * 
 * For any bug, error please contact us
 * We will try to fix it.
 * 
 * Extensionsforjoomla.com - All Rights Reserved
 * 
 */

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
include('./templates/'.$this->template.'/config/colswitch.php');


$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" class="client-nojs">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php 
  $css_string;
  $menutitle = $this->params->get('mobiletext'); 
  $get_less = $this->params->get('enabless'); 
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<script>localStorage.clear(); </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/templateskit.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/templateskit.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  
<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/main.css" type="text/css" />

<?php include('./templates/'.$this->template.'/blocks/config.php'); ?>

  <?php if(
```

Comment: Clearly there is a lot of your page missing... where did it go? I'd suggest contacting the people from whom you bought the script?

Comment: Your code sample is cut in the half at last line `<?php if(`. If you have it the same at your script that means that you missed some copy/paste... Anyway don't want to be rude, however asking such things as incomplete code isn't serious.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the last if statement.

```
<?php if(
```